# PHP: not getting the last row in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a new problem right now, and I was wondering why its not displaying..

Scenario:

I have a duration where the duration is good only until **10:00**....

In my database:

```
bldgName    duration

blgA         9:55
bldgA        9:40
bldgB        1:40
```

As we can see, my last row if I used the "DESC" its look like that... So my last entry in my bldgA is 9:55... I will add another 5s under bldgA and it will become 10:00, which is correct... So here's my database as for now..

Current database after adding the 5 seconds.

```
bldgName    duration

blgA         10:00
blgA         9:55
bldgA        9:40
bldgB        1:40
```

Here's my query:

```
$radio = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName, MAX(fldTotalDuration) as fldTotalDuration FROM tbldata WHERE fldNetname = '".$get_radio."' AND fldMonth = '".$get_month."' AND fldWeek = '".$get_week. "' GROUP BY fldBldgName ORDER BY id, fldBldgName, fldTotalDuration DESC");
```

So when the program read that query above...

the output is like this...

```
bldgName    duration

blgA         9:55
bldgB        1:40
```

This is wrong...

the correct output is

```
bldgName    duration

blgA         10:00
bldgB        1:40
```

And also, I don't have any filtering yet when the duration meets the **10:00**

Thanks for advance...

Comment: What the hell was that? I did not understand a bit of the question

Comment: all i see is a select statement, why dont you try to insert or update

Comment: As stated in the comments of your last question. Stop using VARCHAR or TEXT with time values. You will have huge problems with sorting. In your case seconds and an INT field would fit a lot better. Or also [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what he means.
Seems like you want to get the max duration, is fldTotalDuration to type varchar? if yes it's normal that the max one is 9:55 because the field is alphabetically sorted, I suggest you to change the field type to decimal and it should work.

Bye
Gnagno

Comment: @Gnagno...thanks for understanding my question...I'm using TEXT only in all fields..

Comment: in your case the TEXT field is not the best type, you should change it to decimal, or int :)

Comment: If I changed it to decimal or int, the ":" will never be saved because its not a number.. Thats why i used the TEXT so I can saved also the ":" [colon]

Comment: If the value is stored as decimal it will be returned with a dot as separator, you can simply convert the dot to a colon before printing it: str_replace(".", ":", $youstring) and it's done :)

Comment: Store the amount of seconds as INT or store it like `00:10:00` in TIME.

Comment: @Gnagno..I just changed the type to TIME. and its working now..And also thanks for suggesting me to changed it... Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing it to **INT** or **DECIMAL**, I just decided to change to **TIME**... So its already works now...

And also thank you for commenting and give some ideas thats make it help alot..